# How to compare passwords (Bcrypt hashes) in Symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony, passwords, bcrypt

In setting up a "change password" feature for a site I have a secondary password entry (*where you need to enter your password again before you can change it*).

I need to be able to check the user's current password (*hashed using Bcrypt*) against the password that has been entered.

In my controller action I have:

```
$currentPassword = $request->request->get('password');
$encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
$encodedPassword = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $currentPassword);

if($encodedPassword == $user->getPassword()) { // these don't ever match.
    // ...
}
```

`encodePassword(...)` produces a digest of the password that was entered, but it's not the same as the saved password (*the plaintext is the same*), so I'm thinking that a different salt is being applied and therefore producing the mismatch.

Since Bcrypt incorporates the salt in the password digest, I'm not saving it anywhere.

How can I check if the entered plaintext password matches the stored Bcrypt digest in Symfony 3?

I am not using `FOSUserBundle`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can compare the `$currentPassword` password with the stored one using the `isPasswordValid` method of the encoder service:

`$encoderService = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder')`

and then pass the user object as first argument of the method:

`$match = $encoderService->isPasswordValid($userObject, $currentPassword)`

that will returns `true` if the comparison match or `false` otherwise.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks very much. I somehow missed that in the docs.

Comment: Glad to help @Chris. PS: Sometimes it can be enough to inspect the class methods (using ides shortcuts) to find someting useful for the future :-)